# Excel VBA Consecutive and non-consecutive numbers concatenation

Tags: vba, excel, string-concatenation

I'm new to programming and have been puzzling over this challenge for a while.  I suspect the solution would involve nested conditionals and/or a user defined function.  I have a table similar to this which has been sorted from smallest to largest in the "sheet#" column:

```
QTY Type Sheet#
1    B    1000
5    B    1001
3    B    1002
2    B    1005
7    B    1009
4    B    1010
2    B    1010
3    B    1010
1    B    1011
2    B    1012
6    B    1013
8    B    1013
1    B    1015
1    B    1015
2    B    1016
```

There are several things to consider: Some of the sheet numbers are duplicates, some of the sheet numbers are missing (for example 1006 thru 1008 are missing from the list above)some of the sheet number are consecutive, some of them are duplicates and then consecutive with the next sheet number (as in 1010, 1010, 1010, 1011)

The result I need to produce is three cells: A total of the quantity, a translation of the letter (as in "B" stands for "Beam" and a concatenation of the sheet numbers that would read as follows

```
QTY  Type Sheet#
48   Beams On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009 to 1013, 1015 and 1016
```

The Translation from "B" to "Beams" is only one case.  I have another table on a separate worksheet that lists all the types, eg. B = Beam, C = Column, BR = Brace, PS = Pipe support, etc.

Any guidance would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Quantity can be achieved via `sumif` but you likely need vba for rest. If you're not going to show any effort, please hire someone to do the job.

Comment: Show effort?  I have about two weeks experience with VBA.  My question is asking for suggestions on HOW to accomplish this task using VBA.  I'm not asking for anyone to do all the work.  I thought the point of the this site was to ask questions?!

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the B:C to another area (I placed in G:H)

Use the "Remove duplicates" function under the data tab

In F2 enter: `=SUMIF(B:B,G2,A:A)`

In I2 put in a vlookup formula to pull back the meaning of B or C or whatever

In J2 put the following formula: `=IF(G2<>G1,"On sheets " & H2,IF(AND(H2=H1+1,H2=H3-1),J1,IF(H2=H1+1,J1 & " to " & H2,J1 & ", " & H2)))`

Drag F2, I2 and J2 down.

This is how it looked when I played with some test data (Didn't do the vlookup, it doesn't have a bearing on my tests)

```
QTY TypeSheet#  
48  B   1000    On sheets 1000
48  B   1001    On sheets 1000
48  B   1002    On sheets 1000 to 1002
48  B   1005    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005
48  B   1009    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009
48  B   1010    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009
48  B   1011    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009
48  B   1012    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009
48  B   1013    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009 to 1013
48  B   1015    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009 to 1013, 1015
48  B   1016    On sheets 1000 to 1002, 1005, 1009 to 1013, 1015 to 1016
20  C   1012    On sheets 1012
20  C   1013    On sheets 1012 to 1013
20  C   1015    On sheets 1012 to 1013, 1015
20  C   1016    On sheets 1012 to 1013, 1015 to 1016
```

Once done you can copy and paste as value and simply delete all but the last row per type

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the quick response!  The result you show is exactly what I'm trying to do.  However, I must have done something wrong because instead i am getting this:  "On sheets 221,222,223,224,225,226..."  I made a test sheet and used the exact columns as you described and copied and pasted you formulas.  I took a screen shot but don't see a way to display it here.

Comment: Post what you are doing step by step and I can help you out.

Comment: I edited the above comment with more details.  But here is even more.  i made a test sheet.  In it I placed my data in columns A,B, and C.  I copied B,C to G,H.  Entered the SumIf formula in F2 and copied it down.  Entered the formula in I2 (Vlookup) and your formula in J2 and copied down.  Result is "On sheets 221,222,223,224,225..."

Comment: Oh, and I left out above the step of removing duplicates.  I did in fact do that.

Comment: Highlight your column with the sheets on it, click "Text to columns" under the data tab, Choose delimited and press next, choose tab and click next, choose general and hit finish, Watch your formula suddenly start to work :). This is because the data is set as text, the formula uses a calculation to detect the movement in the sheet number but if it is text it can't work. You could get around this using a "Value" formula but text to columns is easier :)

Comment: Perfect!  I really do thank you for the responses and the help.  Now I can spend some time and write some VBA to do this.  Seeing the formula you made helps me understand the logic better.  Very Nice!

Comment: Glad I could help. Post again if you get stuck on the VBA, I am sure I can help you out with it :)